# Datatables and contains not finding its elements

Tags: javascript, datatables, popup

I have used the datatables plugin, to display some table data, with pagination and search.
It is displayed in a popup i made purely with javascript.
My issue is that i have this code:

```
backdrop.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if(e.target !== popup && !popup.contains(e.target)){
                closeGenericPopup(id);
            }
        });
```

Which is supposed to close the popup if you click outside of it.
But my issue is for some reason, if i click on any of the pagination buttons on the datatables, it will also close the popup. It seems popup does not contain the pagination, even though it definetely does!

I configured my datatables like this:

```
$('.matrixCarTable-container table').DataTable({
        'paging': true,
        'ordering': false,
        'info': false,
    });
```

If curious about the whole popup, this is the code in its entirety.

```
const showGenericPopup = (id) => {
    // creates a popup with a backdrop
    // and a main "popup" that is centered in the window.
    // and a close button.
    // the rest is custom implementation.
    // there are currently 4 sizes classes that can be applied to the popup-backdrop__box element
    // popup--sm
    // popup--md
    // popup--lg
    // popup--xl

    if(document.getElementById("popup-backdrop" + id) === null){

        const backdrop = document.createElement("div");
        backdrop.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop");
        backdrop.setAttribute("id", "popup-backdrop" + id)
        const popup = document.createElement("div");
        popup.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__box");

        const popupContent = document.createElement("div");
        popupContent.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__content");

        const popupHeader = document.createElement("div");
        popupHeader.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__header");


        const closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        closeButton.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__close");

        const closeIcon = document.createElement("i");
        closeIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-times");


        closeButton.appendChild(closeIcon);
        popupHeader.appendChild(closeButton);

        popup.appendChild(popupHeader);
        popup.appendChild(popupContent);

        backdrop.appendChild(popup);
        document.body.appendChild(backdrop);

        popupHeader.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__close").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            closeGenericPopup(id);
        });

        backdrop.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // const ele = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop"+id).querySelector(".popup-backdrop__box");
            if(e.target !== popup && !popup.contains(e.target)){
                closeGenericPopup(id);
            }
        });

        // return the element of the popup not the backdrop, so its easier to add elements to it directly.
        return popupContent;
    }

    const backdrop = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop"+id);
    backdrop.style.display = "block";

    return backdrop.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__content")
}
const closeGenericPopup = (id) => {
    const backdropElement = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop" + id);
    backdropElement.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__box").classList = "popup-backdrop__box"; // reset any sizes set to it.

    const popupContentElement = backdropElement.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__content");
    popupContentElement.innerHTML = "";

    backdropElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    showMatrixCarsOfCategory(1);
});


const showMatrixCarsOfCategory = (category) => {
    const popup = showGenericPopup("matrixCarsOfCategory");
    popup.parentElement.classList.add("popup--lg");

    const heading = document.createElement("h2");
    heading.innerText = "Biler i kategorien";
    heading.style.textAlign = "center";

    popup.appendChild(heading);
    
    const table = show();
    popup.appendChild(table);
  
     $('.matrixCarTable-container table').DataTable({
        'paging': true,
        'ordering': false,
        'info': false,
     });
}

const show =  () =>{
    
    const matrixCarTableContainer = document.createElement("div");
    matrixCarTableContainer.setAttribute("class", "matrixCarTable-container");


    const table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("class", "matrixCarTable");

    const thead = document.createElement("thead");
    const headRow = document.createElement("tr");

    const checkAllCheckboxTh = document.createElement("th");
    const checkAllCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkAllCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkAllCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        // This checks all the checkboxes of the current "page".
        let checkStatus = e.target.checked === true ? true : false;
        const checkboxes = matrixCarTableContainer.querySelectorAll(".matrix-checkbox");
        for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            const checkbox = checkboxes[i];
            if(checkbox === null || checkbox === undefined || checkbox.length === 0){
            }else{
                checkbox.checked = checkStatus;
            }
        }
    });
    checkAllCheckboxTh.appendChild(checkAllCheckbox);

    const brandTh = document.createElement("th");
    brandTh.textContent = "Mærke";
    const modelTh = document.createElement("th");
    modelTh.textContent = "Model";
    const variantTh = document.createElement("th");
    variantTh.textContent = "Variant";
    const dbiTh = document.createElement("th");
    dbiTh.textContent = "DBI Nr.";
    const actionsTh = document.createElement("th");
    actionsTh.textContent = "Actions";

    headRow.appendChild(checkAllCheckboxTh);
    headRow.appendChild(brandTh);
    headRow.appendChild(modelTh);
    headRow.appendChild(variantTh);
    headRow.appendChild(dbiTh);
    headRow.appendChild(actionsTh);
    thead.appendChild(headRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);


    const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        const row = document.createElement("tr");

        const checkbox = document.createElement("td");
        const checkboxInput = document.createElement("input");
        checkboxInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkboxInput.setAttribute("class", "matrix-checkbox");
        checkbox.appendChild(checkboxInput);

        const brand = document.createElement("td");
        brand.textContent = "Mercedes"; // TODO: get proper value
        const model = document.createElement("td");
        model.textContent = "Sprinter 319"; // TODO: get proper value
        const variant = document.createElement("td");
        variant.textContent = "BlueTEC AMG Line aut. 4Matic Van"; // TODO: get proper value
        const dbiNumber = document.createElement("td");
        dbiNumber.textContent = "123"; // TODO: get proper value
        const actions = document.createElement("td");


        const actionsEditButton = document.createElement("button");
        actionsEditButton.innerHTML = "<i class=\"far fa-edit\"></i>";
        actionsEditButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            // TODO: Show edit popup with relevant data.
            showUpdateMatrixCarPopup(1); // TODO: Get car ID
        });
        const actionsDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
        actionsDeleteButton.innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-trash-alt\"></i>";
        actionsDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            confirmAction("Er du sikker på at du vil slette bilen?", function () {
                // TODO: Add delete logic
                // TODO: Refresh Table with updated data.
            }, "confirmCarDelete"); // TODO: Add carID here
        });
        actions.appendChild(actionsEditButton);
        actions.appendChild(actionsDeleteButton);

        row.appendChild(checkbox);
        row.appendChild(brand);
        row.appendChild(model);
        row.appendChild(variant);
        row.appendChild(dbiNumber);
        row.appendChild(actions);

        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    matrixCarTableContainer.appendChild(table);

    return matrixCarTableContainer;
}
const showGenericPopup = (id) => {
    // creates a popup with a backdrop
    // and a main "popup" that is centered in the window.
    // and a close button.
    // the rest is custom implementation.
    // there are currently 4 sizes classes that can be applied to the popup-backdrop__box element
    // popup--sm
    // popup--md
    // popup--lg
    // popup--xl

    if(document.getElementById("popup-backdrop" + id) === null){

        const backdrop = document.createElement("div");
        backdrop.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop");
        backdrop.setAttribute("id", "popup-backdrop" + id)
        const popup = document.createElement("div");
        popup.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__box");

        const popupContent = document.createElement("div");
        popupContent.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__content");

        const popupHeader = document.createElement("div");
        popupHeader.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__header");


        const closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        closeButton.setAttribute("class", "popup-backdrop__close");

        const closeIcon = document.createElement("i");
        closeIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-times");


        closeButton.appendChild(closeIcon);
        popupHeader.appendChild(closeButton);

        popup.appendChild(popupHeader);
        popup.appendChild(popupContent);

        backdrop.appendChild(popup);
        document.body.appendChild(backdrop);

        popupHeader.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__close").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            closeGenericPopup(id);
        });

        backdrop.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // const ele = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop"+id).querySelector(".popup-backdrop__box");
            if(e.target !== popup && !popup.contains(e.target)){
                closeGenericPopup(id);
            }
        });

        // return the element of the popup not the backdrop, so its easier to add elements to it directly.
        return popupContent;
    }

    const backdrop = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop"+id);
    backdrop.style.display = "block";

    return backdrop.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__content")
}
const closeGenericPopup = (id) => {
    const backdropElement = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop" + id);
    backdropElement.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__box").classList = "popup-backdrop__box"; // reset any sizes set to it.

    const popupContentElement = backdropElement.querySelector(".popup-backdrop__content");
    popupContentElement.innerHTML = "";

    backdropElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: create a snippet with sample data ., so that we can cut to the chase of the issuse?

Comment: @Sund'er Added the snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Check this lines in your code ., it is closing the popup.,

after commenting the line , the pagination works fine.

```
   backdrop.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        
            // const ele = document.getElementById("popup-backdrop"+id).querySelector(".popup-backdrop__box");
            if(e.target !== popup && !popup.contains(e.target)){
            // alert(this.id); -- This shows the id of the entire popup
             //  closeGenericPopup(id);
            }
        });
```

Comment: ... Yes its supposed to be there.. Otherwise it will never close the popup! The issue is that I am clicking an element inside the popup, and then closes.

Comment: what is the element you are click ?

Comment: The pagination that datatables is generating.

Comment: you are using closeGenericPopup(id); , two times in you code., one is for close button with class name, other one is the above code, the code doesn't have any class name so the backdrop is the div you are populating the entire datatables ,so it trigger the above event, try to ignore the pagination click event with the class name. if you do so you can avoid the it will not close the entire backdrop div.